# schedule jobs to be run in the past

Tags: apex, asyncapexjob, schedule

I have a scheduled job whose "Next Scheduled Run" is set to a date in the past:

[image]

Cron expression:

0 30 20 * * ? *

Does it mean that this scheduled job will never run?
What could be the reason for this issue?

Comment: It might be helpful to add the `cron` expression for this job. (You can review `cron` expressions with `SELECT CronJobDetail.Name, CronExpression FROM CronTrigger` in the Developer Console).